# Repeat an iteration of an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, loops, indexing

Consider I have a loop with a conditional inside, if the condition is true then the current iteration of the loop has to be repeated. For example, consider the following method. Read the note inside the if statement.

```
def func1(arr)
  size = arr.size - 1
  max = arr[size]
  0.upto(size) do |x|
    if (*boolean statement*)
      *repeat current iteration*
    end
  end
  func2(arr)
end
```

How would I go about doing this? In case you are wondering why I need this is because I'm modifying the array such that if the conditional is true for a given x, then the element at index x is removed and placed at the end of the array. If the loop continues then it skips the element after x because this one now has the index of the one removed. In java this is done with the continue keyword I think, is there a ruby equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `max = arr[size]` for? Don't write it if it is not doing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Use `redo`:

```
def func1(arr)
  size = arr.size - 1
  max = arr[size]
  0.upto(size) do |x|
    redo if (*boolean statement*)
  end
  func2(arr)
end
```

Comment: Wow, Ruby sometimes looks like a big hack. How does this even work for general Enumerators? I cannot imagine this to have well-defined behaviour in every case...

Comment: @NiklasB. Internally, down at the assembly level, I'm sure it is just a `goto` (more specifically a [jump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMP_(x86_instruction)) of one form or another).

Comment: It can't be, because it works with stateful generators as well (like one reading lines from a file). I think it just caches the arguments passed to the block and then calls the block again with the same arguments if you call redo inside the block. I initially thought this would be some kind of call_cc/setjmp magic which would be pretty scare, but gladly it isn't :)

Comment: @NiklasB. It doesn't look like it caches the arguments. Here's an example: `1.upto(5) { |i| p i; i = 4; redo if i == 4 }`. The output is `1 4 4 4 ...` with newlines in between the numbers. `i` is modified within the block, and it seems to retain this value on the `redo`. So it does look like a simple `goto`.

Comment: `i` is not modified in your example. Integers are immutable. Just check the following: `e = Enumerator.new { |y| y << [1] ;y << [1] }; cnt = 1; e.each { |x| puts "%s:%s" % [x.object_id, x.to_s]; x << 2; redo if (cnt-=1) >= 0 }`

Comment: Also, `goto` is far from simple. It's just impossible to redo I/O for example, so what you're gonna do if somebody does `f = File.open("somefile","r"); e = Enumerator.new {|y| y<<f.readline; y << f.readline }` and then calls `redo` while iterating over the generator?

Comment: I don't critizise your answer by  the way, you're completely right :) I was just initially confused about `redo` semantics because it seems quite arbitrary, but actually there is a semi-good solution for it and it's not your problem anyway.

Comment: @NiklasB. In your example with the `Enumerator.new { |y| y << [1] ;y << [1] }` the `redo` jumps straight back to the first line of the block, which is the `puts` instruction. It doesn't call the enumerator. For the `File.open` example, say you then do `e.each { |line| puts line; ... }` If that contains a `redo`, it will `puts line` again. If no change was made to `line`, then it will be repeated. If it was modified before the `redo`, then it will `puts` the modified line. `redo` does not cause an additional line to be read from the file.

Comment: I see, if by goto you mean jumping to the beginni g of the block again, then that is actually equivalent to what I said. Nevermind.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks for helping to clarify this point for myself and probably others. I had to learn about how `Enumerator.new` works in order for me to just respond to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question it seems you simply
need to replace your 'if' conditional with a 'while' one:

```
def func1(arr)
  size = arr.size - 1
  max = arr[size]
  0.upto(size) do |x|
    while (*boolean statement*)
      *repeat current iteration*
    end
  end
  func2(arr)
end
```